# Sort dictionary by key - Ramda

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

In my program, I am trying to take an array of items (rooms in this case), filter it by some property (rooms with more than 10 seats in), group them into groups that can be stored in a dictionary (group by the area the room is in), and then sort by the dictionary's key.

[image]

To do this, I am using the following code

```
import { ascend, filter, groupBy, pipe, sort } from "ramda";

class Room {
    // Number of seats in the room
    public seats!: number;

    // Area on site, an area can have many rooms
    public area!: string;

    // Name of the room
    public room!: number;
}

class NamedRoomDictionary {
    [index: string]: Room[];
}

const GetRoomsWithMoreThanTenSeats = (rooms: Room[]): Room[] =>
    filter(room => room.seats > 10, rooms);

const GroupByArea = (rooms: Room[]): NamedRoomDictionary =>
    groupBy(room => room.area, rooms);

const SortByArea = (rooms: NamedRoomDictionary): NamedRoomDictionary =>
    sort(ascend(room => room.index), rooms)

const SortBigRoomsByArea = pipe(
    GetRoomsWithMoreThanTenSeats,
    GroupByArea,
  SortByArea
);

const rooms: Room[] = [
  {room: 1, area: 'A', seats: 15},
  {room: 2, area: 'D', seats: 5},
  {room: 3, area: 'R', seats: 8},
  {room: 4, area: 'E', seats: 14},
  {room: 5, area: 'A', seats: 458},
  {room: 6, area: 'F', seats: 10},
  {room: 7, area: 'A', seats: 4},
  {room: 8, area: 'A', seats: 256},
  {room: 9, area: 'D', seats: 100} ];

const sorted = SortBigRoomsByArea(rooms);

console.log(sorted)
```

This can be seen and run at this [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@DanJBower/Sorted-Rooms) project.

However, I am getting the following errors.

> Property 'index' does not exist on type 'Room[]'.ts(2339)

The above error relates to `room.index` on the line `sort(ascend(room => room.index), rooms)`

> Argument of type 'NamedRoomDictionary' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly Room[][]'.
>     Type 'NamedRoomDictionary' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly Room[][]': length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.ts(2345)

The above error relates to `rooms` on the line `sort(ascend(room => room.index), rooms)`.

A working [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@DanJBower/Grouped-Rooms) can be seen here. This does not sort the groups. It only puts things into groups and then displays them.

I'm fairly new to the whole typescript syntax / Ramda library so any pointers for fixing this would be appreciated.

---

Output of [just grouping Repl.it](https://repl.it/@DanJBower/Grouped-Rooms)

```
{ A:
   [ { room: 1, area: 'A', seats: 15 },
     { room: 5, area: 'A', seats: 458 },
     { room: 8, area: 'A', seats: 256 } ],
  E: [ { room: 4, area: 'E', seats: 14 } ],
  D: [ { room: 9, area: 'D', seats: 100 } ] }
```

Desired output of [sorting repl.it](https://repl.it/@DanJBower/Sorted-Rooms)

```
{ A:
   [ { room: 1, area: 'A', seats: 15 },
     { room: 5, area: 'A', seats: 458 },
     { room: 8, area: 'A', seats: 256 } ],
  D: [ { room: 9, area: 'D', seats: 100 } ],
  E: [ { room: 4, area: 'E', seats: 14 } ] }
```

Comment: can you update with your definition of `NamedRoomDictionary` and `Room`

Comment: @TreeNguyen The code I am using is seen as is on the post above. There are now also two repl.it links in the question. The first tries to sort the list and shows the errors. The second does not try to sort it and shows the grouping working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this list:

```
[
  {room: 1, area: 'A', seats: 15},
  {room: 2, area: 'D', seats: 5},
  {room: 3, area: 'R', seats: 8},
  {room: 4, area: 'E', seats: 14},
  {room: 5, area: 'A', seats: 458},
  {room: 6, area: 'F', seats: 10},
  {room: 7, area: 'A', seats: 4},
  {room: 8, area: 'A', seats: 256},
  {room: 9, area: 'D', seats: 100} ];
```

In order to have a sorted list of rooms by `area` where `seats >= 10`, you could:

1. Keep only the rooms with `seats` >= 10
2. Then sort the resulting list on the `area`

```js
const rooms = [
  {room: 1, area: 'A', seats: 15},
  {room: 2, area: 'D', seats: 5},
  {room: 3, area: 'R', seats: 8},
  {room: 4, area: 'E', seats: 14},
  {room: 5, area: 'A', seats: 458},
  {room: 6, area: 'F', seats: 10},
  {room: 7, area: 'A', seats: 4},
  {room: 8, area: 'A', seats: 256},
  {room: 9, area: 'D', seats: 100} ];


const z = compose(sortBy(prop('area')), filter(propSatisfies(lte(10), 'seats')));

console.log(

  z(rooms)

)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {compose, sortBy, prop, filter, propSatisfies, lte} = R;</script>
```

In order to group rooms by `area` where `seats >= 10`, you could

1. Keep only the rooms with `seats` >= 10
2. Then group the resulting list on the `area`

```js
const rooms = [
  {room: 1, area: 'A', seats: 15},
  {room: 2, area: 'D', seats: 5},
  {room: 3, area: 'R', seats: 8},
  {room: 4, area: 'E', seats: 14},
  {room: 5, area: 'A', seats: 458},
  {room: 6, area: 'F', seats: 10},
  {room: 7, area: 'A', seats: 4},
  {room: 8, area: 'A', seats: 256},
  {room: 9, area: 'D', seats: 100} ];


const z = compose(groupBy(prop('area')), filter(propSatisfies(lte(10), 'seats')));

console.log(

  z(rooms)

)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {compose, groupBy, prop, filter, propSatisfies, lte} = R;</script>
```

The difference between the two snippets is the use of `sortBy` vs `groupBy` depending on the use case.

Comment: If you'll `sortBy(prop('area'))` after filtering, the groups keys would retain the order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was more looking to do this using pipe. My only issue is that there are errors with the sort function. If you wouldn't mind looking at the repl.it links in the question, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure. Please note that `pipe` and `compose` are pretty similar, the main difference being the order of the composition.

Answer (score 2):

Your requested output structure is not something Ramda is particularly designed to support.  Objects serve in dual roles in JS, as dictionaries and as records.  But neither of these types has an inherent order to them.  Ramda wants to think of objects with the same values for the same keys as inherently equal.  Thus `R.equals({a: 1, b: 2}, {b: 2, a: 1}` yields `true`.  So, while you can group by the `area` property, and you could choose to sort the (array) keys of the result, Ramda will not intrinsically order the resulting object for you.  And if you order it yourself, one day a Ramda function might reorder it for you.  (Ramda has sometimes considered sorting object keys alphabetically to deal with some of these issues.)

But a simpler output structure is quite easy to achieve, where the items are filtered and then sorted according their group, but still kept in a flat array:

```js
const sortBigRoomsByArea = pipe (
  filter ( ({seats}) => seats > 10 ),
  sortBy (prop ('area'))
)
```

This is essentially the same answer customcommander gave.

If you wanted further sorting of the results, say by descending numbers of seats, then it would make sense to switch to `sortWith`:

```js
const sortBigRoomsByArea = pipe (
  filter ( ({seats}) => seats > 10 ),
  sortWith ([
    ascend ( prop ('area') ),
    descend ( prop ('seats') )
  ])
)

const rooms= [{room: 1, area: 'A', seats: 15}, {room: 2, area: 'D', seats: 5}, {room: 3, area: 'R', seats: 8}, {room: 4, area: 'E', seats: 14}, {room: 5, area: 'A', seats: 458}, {room: 6, area: 'F', seats: 10}, {room: 7, area: 'A', seats: 4}, {room: 8, area: 'A', seats: 256}, {room: 9, area: 'D', seats: 100}]

console .log (
  sortBigRoomsByArea (rooms)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {ascend, descend, filter, pipe, prop, sortWith} = R   </script>
```